# Regular expression using grep to match the beginning and end of a string

Tags: regex

I have to find running file which will have format like:

```
"Throughput_Monitor_20141211T111311.792-0-V4.4.6_UE_9"
```

I am using regular expression  as:

```
ps aux | grep -i [^Throughput_Monitor_]*[UE_9]$
```

but I am getting not only the above file but couple of other files. Could anyone help me find the regular expression? I am not sure where I am making mistake.

thanks

Comment: `[]` probably don't do what you think they do.  They are [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: `ps aux | grep -i '^Throughput_Monitor_.*UE_9$'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use anchors in command line since your command line may have some additional stuff.

You can use:

```
ps aux | grep -Ei '\bThroughput_Monitor_.*UE_9\b'
```

Better to use `pgrep` if you have it:

```
pgrep -ifl 'Throughput_Monitor_.*UE_9'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ps aux | grep -i ^Throughput_Monitor_.*?UE_9$
```

Guess this should work for you.